# Screenshot for each DOM node

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

How can I create screenshots for every DOM node in any site?

I tried to use headless browser (puppeteer) and it's working only when I know XPath or Selector of some element.
But how to I can receive XPath or Selector for all elements?

```
async function screenshotDOMElement(opts = {}) {
const padding = 'padding' in opts ? opts.padding : 0;
const path = 'path' in opts ? opts.path : null;
const selector = opts.selector;

if (!selector)
    throw Error('Please provide a selector.');

const rect = await page.evaluate(selector => {
    const element =
     document.evaluate(selector, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    if (!element)
        return null;
    const {x, y, width, height} = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log (x,y,width,height)
    return {left: x, top: y, width, height, id: element.id};
}, selector);

if (!rect)
    throw Error(`Could not find element that matches selector: ${selector}.`);

return await page.screenshot({
    path,
    clip: {
        x: rect.left - padding,
        y: rect.top - padding,
        width: rect.width + padding * 2,
        height: rect.height + padding * 2
    }
});
}
```

Also I tried to use `HtmlAgilityPack` (C#) and enumerate each node in HtmlDocument by XPath, but this XPath can't work with `puppeteer`

I need to use puppeteer 'cos it's the best instrument for screenshot-task by XPath or Selector

Who can help me?

Comment: Your question is of very low quality, which library are you using? What is `page`? I want to help but I feel like I can't because I'm missing a lot of information. If `page.evaluate` loops through every item, why not `page.screenshot` inside that?

Comment: @Tvde1 may be. Page is any web page in World-Wide-Web. 
U need a try to create page.evaluate loops and call screenshot for it. 
It's common and unresolved problem (get screenshot for every available element on any web page)  
Last moth I tried to get result for it 
And last my step was "puppeteer" headless browser.
Pls don't decrease points of question.

Comment: Seriously, what is `page`? How do you create the object? Is it a string of HTML? Is it from a library?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With puppeteer, you don't need to use the whole page screenshot anymore, since it has [elementHandle.screenshot([options])](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.10.0/docs/api.md#elementhandlescreenshotoptions). Here's what you can do:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://example.com');

// get a list of all elements - same as document.querySelectorAll('*')
const elements = await page.$$('*')

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  try {
    // get screenshot of a particular element
    await elements[i].screenshot({path: `${i}.png`})
  } catch(e) {
    // if element is 'not visible', spit out error and continue
    console.log(`couldnt take screenshot of element with index: ${i}. cause: `,  e)
  }
}
await browser.close();
```

Notice than puppeteer fails to get screenshots for some elements that are invisible or covered by other elements, etc. In such a case, you need to catch an error and move on.

Comment: I don’t know how it works, but when the page has many elements, this cycle will stop without errors, it will just wait for something ...

Comment: Try to execute it for youtube

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров Just tried - works for me on youtube. `node count: 1695 successful: 1094 not visible: 601 other: 0`. Doesn't seem like the problem with the code.

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров Well, it's the same code plus a little bit of logging: https://gist.github.com/shkaper/5421a9135f26ab57d368ae8bb39dcd22

Comment: I tried run your code but it's stop at next moment : https://ibb.co/bTrRZq

Comment: may be need I run it from powershell instead cmd?

Comment: It's hard to tell. I ran in on mac. Try with a different selector, or reverse the array of nodes and start screenshotting from the last node in the array. Or try launching puppeteer in a full mode with `puppeteer.launch({headless: false})` and see what's going on on the page. Or set up breakpoints, launch the script with `--inspect` flag and go through the execution step by step. The possibilities are countless.

Comment: as I understand when node trying to execute screenshot then webpage is stop, but when I toogle resize of browser window it's saving screenshot and turn of next node. summary : when node is visible and can create screenshot, chromium can't do it and just stopping, but when user toggling size of browser it's can create screenshot and continue. magic. I can create video if u need

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров That is curious indeed. However, I think the problem you describe deserves its own question.

Comment: also navigation between tabs can avoid sleep and create screenshot 
After your ran it in on mac have u 1094 screenshots?

Comment: pls check my answer below